# Read from servlet a form input with name like input[]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I want to read some inputs from a form in my JSP page where each input has the same name. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vr7etpLr/2/)

How can I read these inputs from my servlet?

I tried  `String[] description = request.getParameterValues("description");` but it doesn't work..

Is there a way to loop and read these values?

```js
counter = 0;
var dataList = $('.products');
var jsonOptions = [{
  "product": "11111",
  "description": "description 1"
}, {
  "product": "22222",
  "description": "description 2"
}, {
  "product": "33333",
  "description": "description 3"
}];

jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {

  var option = '<option value="' + item.product + '">' + item.description + '</option>';

  dataList.append(option);
});

$(function() {
  $('body').on('input', '.product,.products', function() {

    var i = this.value;
    var description = "";
    var productsInBox = 0;

    jsonOptions.forEach(function(a) {
      if (a.product == i) {
        description = a.description;
        productsInBox = a.productsInBox;
      }
    });
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.description').val(description);


  });
});





$('#form1').on('click', '.addButtonDED', function() {
    var $template = $('.form-group:last').clone(true, true).find('input').val('').end().
    find('.addButtonDED').removeClass('addButtonDED').addClass('removeButtonDED').end()
      .find('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus').end();
    $template.insertAfter('.form-group:last');
  })

  // Remove button click handler
  .on('click', '.removeButtonDED', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('.form-group');
    $row.remove();
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <fieldset>


    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" list="products" class="form-control product" name="product[]" />
        <datalist id="products" class="products"></datalist>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="" type="text" class="form-control description" name=" description[]" />
      </div>



      <div class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addButtonDED"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10 ">
      <button type="submit" name="formAction" value="next" class="btn btn-primary">sUBMIT</button>

    </div>



  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

changing the name to description should work

`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" />`

or
`String[] description = request.getParameterValues("description[]");`

I would prefer the first one as it is less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Either use "description" as the name in your <input>s, or use `request.getParameterValues("description[]")`, but use the same name on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

this will work.

```
String[] description = request.getParameterValues("description[]");
```